# What is the significance of Kat's despising of Hemingway?

Tags: character, 10-things-i-hate-about

In *10 Things I Hate About You*, Kat shows an intense despite against Hemingway and even got scolded for being racist by her teacher because of her opinion.

I am sure Kat is not being racist here but her comments on Hemingway sound more like remarks full of disgust.

But what was the reason for it? Why does she despise him that much?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Kat's exact quote in the film was in response to a fellow classmate calling Hemingway a romantic:

> Romantic? Hemingway? He was an abusive, alcoholic misogynist who
>   squandered half his life...hanging around Picasso trying to nail his
>   leftovers.

Let's break down Kat's accusations of [Hemingway](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2014/02/23/the-perils-of-being-a-hemingway-wife.html):

- **Abusive** - Hemingway was mentally abusive to each of his four wives and many lovers.  He was famous for his volatile temper.  There is no definitive evidence that Hemingway physically abused his many lovers, but he did make a lot of them suffer mental abuse.
- **Alcoholic** - Hemingway was a heavy drinker for the majority of his life.
- **Misogynist** - Hemingway was definitely a "man's man" and had somewhat of a controversial view of women.  For example, there is a passage from a [letter](http://flavorwire.com/417099/7-breathtakingly-sexist-quotes-by-famous-and-respected-male-authors/2) that he wrote to his editor, Maxwell Perkins in 1943:

  > A woman ruined Scott [Fitzgerald]. It wasn’t just Scott ruining
  >   himself. But **why couldn’t he have told her to go to hell?** Because she
  >   was sick. It’s being sick makes them act so bloody awful usually and
  >   it’s because they’re sick you can’t treat them as you should. The
  >   first great gift for a man is to be healthy and the second, maybe
  >   greater, is to fall [in] with healthy women. **You can always trade one
  >   healthy woman in on another.** But start with a sick woman and see where
  >   you get. Sick in the head or sick anywhere. But sick anywhere and in a
  >   little while they are sick in the head. **If they locked up all the
  >   women who were crazy** — but why speculate — I’ve known goddamned good
  >   ones; but take as good a woman as Pauline — a hell of a wonderful
  >   woman — and once she turns mean. Although, of course, it is your own
  >   actions that turn her mean. Mine I mean. Not yours. Anyway let’s leave
  >   the subject. **If you leave a woman, though, you probably ought to shoot
  >   her. It would save enough trouble in the end even if they hanged you.**

  Hemingway was an avid boxer, big game hunter, fisherman and outdoorsman.
- **Nailing Picasso's leftovers** - Picasso and Hemingway were acquainted in Paris and were introduced to eachother by Art enthusiast Gertrude Stein in the 1920's.  Both were ego maniacs and womanizers.  It is always just assumed that Hemingway and Picasso competed with each other for women because they competed with each other in every other way.  There is a woman named [Sara Murphy](http://www.nytimes.com/1994/04/21/arts/a-face-in-the-gallery-of-picasso-s-muses-is-given-a-new-name-425725.html) who both Picasso and Hemingway claimed as a muse.

Kat also despises Hemingway because she is seen as a passionate feminist who stands against all of the male stereotypes which Hemingway represents.

She would rather read literature by female writers.  She suggests to Mr. Morgan that the class read works by female authors:

> What about Sylvia Plath...or Charlotte Bronte or Simone de Beauvoir?

Comment: "[...] held the view that women were put on this earth to cater to and please a man " : citation needed. That sounds a bit exaggerated to me. Macho certainly but mysogynist?

Comment: @drolex How many citations do you want?  Hemingway's personal letters and even his writings to his wife in _A Moveable Feast_ are all evidence of him being a misogynist.  There's a fine line  between being a misogynist and "macho" anyways.  The link that I provided explains how he treated women as well.

Comment: Well the last paragraph of your link tends to minimize this mysogyny, so the use of this heavy term should be better referenced in my opinion. That might be true, but calling someone a mysogynist should be carefully weighted (there are quite a few women in his novels that don't correspond at all to this viewpoint of "women were put on earth to cater and please a man"). To put it shortly it sounds more like an opinion than a fact (again it can very well be true, but it's hard to tell with the form of the answer).

Comment: @drolex Edited with one of many sources.  I removed my "unreferenced opinion"  I am not the one that called him a misogynist, the character in the film did.  I was just explaining why she would think that, especially given that she's a feminist.

Comment: @drolex doesn't matter if you don't think that, Kat certainly did.

Comment: @cde presicely that's the point of the question: why does she think that?

Comment: She (kat and SS) explained why. You just disagree. `That sounds a bit exaggerated to me.`

Comment: @cde I imagine if you were writing a "shrew-ish" character, an exaggerated dislike for the masculine characteristics/misogyny/etc would be one of their qualities. It's her opinion, and it tells us about her and what a tough time Patrick will have.

Comment: Wowza, now I hate Hemingway too.

Comment: @MissMonicaE Well, Hemingway is actually one of my favorite authors.  I love his style of writing and his story telling abilities.  But, yeah.  He was kind of an ass IRL ;)

Comment: [Congratulations, for the Rewards for the best answer of 1st quarter of 2017](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2722/1190)

Answer (score 19):

Why?...she says why...she disapproves of him **as a person**.

> Hemingway?! He was an **abusive alcoholic misogynist** who squandered half his life hanging around Picasso trying to nail his leftovers.

As for racism, the teacher doesn't actually accuse her of that; it's more about the fact that, in his eyes, she's protesting about the wrong things.

[**Transcript**](http://www.awesomefilm.com/script/tenthings_transcript.html)

> MR. MORGAN: And Kat.  I want to thank you for your point of view.
>
> *She smiles to herself, her social indignation justified.*
>
> MR. MORGAN
> (continuing)
> I know how difficult it must be for you to overcome all those years of upper middle class suburban oppression. It must be tough.
>
> *She deflates and becomes bitter again.*
>
> MR. MORGAN (continuing) But the next time you storm around the PTA crusading for better lunch meat, or whatever it is you white girls complain about, ask them why they can’t buy a book written by a black man!

Answer (score 8):

She [explained](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0147800/quotes) it herself:

> Romantic? Hemingway? He was an abusive, alcoholic misogynist who
>   squandered half of his life hanging around Picasso trying to nail his
>   leftovers.

I believe that for the rebellious, feminist-oriented Kat the fact that he was a mysogynist was the most important. Whether this is true is a different story, you can see [this](https://www.quora.com/How-big-of-a-misogynist-was-Hemingway) Quora discussion for more information on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the implication of that scene was that she was transferring her dislike for what one particular guy did to her years prior onto guys in general, using Feminist language. She saw Hemingway as an exemplar of that kind of guy.

The teacher likely felt unfairly personally attacked by this (being both a guy, and in fact the guy who assigned this particular writer), and decided to give her a taste of her own medicine. As an African-American talking to a very privileged white person, race is what he had to work with. Was it unfair and unreasonable? Probably. But so was dumping on him (and disrupting class) because some other guy got her drunk during her freshman year.

Comment: Just as a personal note, this is what I believe the writers had in mind. I'm not trying to imply that I personally think this would be what is motivating such actions if I saw them in real life. This was a work of *fiction*.